# Array Prototype toString() vs Object toString()

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var d = [];
console.log(typeof d); // weird!
console.log(d.toString()); //Prints nothing since there are no elements in the array
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(d)); // better!
```

When I ran the code above the first console.log prints object, which is expected since an array is an object and the second console.log prints [object Array]. I am a little confused on how `Object.prototype.toString.call(d)` works.

So I know the toString method on the array prototype simply tries to print out the elements inside of an array. But when you call the toString method on the base Object's prototype what exactly does that toString method do? Does it try to print out the elements of the array as well? Also does the toString method on the base Object use the keyword `this` since we are using `.call` which changes what the this keyword points when a function is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `Object.prototype.toString` (or a simplified version) as this:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
  var myType = (typeof this)[0].toUpperCase() + (typeof this).substr(1);
  return "[Object " + myType + "]";
}
```

<sup>(unrelated: see note at bottom of answer for explanation of what (typeof this)[0] does, but assume for now that myType = 'String' for a string, 'Array' for an array, etc)</sup>

and it's different from `[].toString()` because since an array is a just a child of an object, `toString` for array is just overridden:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.join(',');
}
```

and when you call `Object.prototype.toString` you're referring to the first function, and `[].toString` is referring to the second. It's no different from if you did this:

```
function MyClass() {};
var x = new MyClass;

x.toString(); // prints "[object Object]"

MyClass.prototype.toString = function() { return 'hello!' }
x.toString(); // prints "hello!"

// and we can call Object's toString method instead
Object.prototype.toString.call(x); // prints "[object Object]"
```

the first call invoked `Object.prototype.toString` because `MyClass` is a subclass of `Object` and doesn't have its own `toString` method. Then when we give `MyClass` a `toString` method, calling `x.toString` uses the `toString` method on `MyClass`, and finally we can again call our "superclass" `toString` method with `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`.

---

**what does (typeof this)[0] do?** `(typeof this)` returns the name of your class. `typeof ""` returns `"string"`, `typeof 5` returns `"number"`, etc (note, arrays actually have type `object`, and yet `[] instanceof Array` is true!). However this is always lowercase. `Object.prototype.toString` returns a string such as `"Object String"` where the type of the object is upper case. `(typeof this)[0]` is saying *"give me the first character of the string"*, and `(typeof this).substr(1)` says *"give me every character beyond the first character of the string"*. Again, the string here `(typeof this)` is just a lowercase representation of the object. The `toUpperCase` call makes sure that the first character is capitalized.

Comment: Hi! In this line here: var myType = (typeof this)[0].toUpperCase() + (typeof this).substr(1); Why do you have [0] right after (typeof this)? Can you please walk through what the variable myType will be? Like what will (typeof this)[0].toUpperCase() print out? Array? And the (typeof this).substr(1). Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, (typeof this) returns the name of your class. typeof "" returns string, typeof [] returns array, etc. However this is always lowercase. Object.prototype.toString returns a string such as "Object String" where the type of the object is upper case. (typeof this)[0] is saying "give me the first character of the string, and (typeof this).substr(1) says "give me every character beyond the first character of the string". Again, the string here (typeof this) is just a lowercase representation of the object. The toUpperCase call makes sure that the first character is capitalized.

Comment: Ohh ok! I was not aware that you can access characters in a string using [0]. So in this case (typeof this) would return array, with a lowercase a and you accessing a and making it uppercase.

Comment: (typeof this) would return a string, but you can enumerate a string as if it were an array, and yes you are exactly right, we are making the first character upper case :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! So essentially when you (typeof this)[0] are you boxing the string returned from the typeof method into an object?

Comment: @Macmee "*typeof [] returns array*" - no, definitely not. Your `Object.prototype.toString` implementation is overly simplified. Simplifying may be fine as the method behaviour is not key to the question, but if you're doing so on purpose you must mention it.

Comment: @Bergi excellent point, see my edit and thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

`Object.prototype.toString` is the base implementation of `.toString()` that all other objects inherit unless they specifically override `.toString()`.  It's default implementation is to produce an output that looks like this:

```
"[object Type]"
```

where `type` is something like `Object`, `Array`, etc...  So, for a plain JS object, it would produce:

```
 "[object Object]"
```

And, for an Array, it would produce:

```
 "[object Array]"
```

---

Meanwhile, the Array class overrides `.toString()` to provide a concatenation of the array contents.

So, if you have an array or might have an array object, and what you want is the  first type of `.toString()`, then you can call:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
```

And, this will tell you whether you have an array object or not.  If it's an array, you will get:

```
"[object Array]"
```

Other than the newer `Array.isArray()`, this is generally considered the best way to tell if your object is an array.

---

Here's a working snippet that illustrates:

```js
var obj = {greeting: "hello"};
var arr = [1,2,3];

log(obj.toString());
log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj))

log(arr.toString());
log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr))

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatype detection in JavaScript could be improved. It's one of the areas that definitely could. To be fair, though, that may be because JavaScript was created in 11 days to be a basic runtime for handling the DOM; and that it does! Only on special occasions, therefore, have I needed to do so.

Furthermore, JavaScript is oriented around the very simplified class system, known as prototypical, which makes coercion a typical practice. Thus, in order to provide methods and properties to any data type, they coerce to object-types temporarily. That's one of the fundamental aspects to the approach. So that, and the fact that host objects, such as elements, have no constructor interface or standard basically explains the data type situation. (And of course, we have built-ins and natives like `Date`, `Math`, etc.)

Again, JavaScript still does what it set out to do, and especially well in cases, but could certainly be improved!

I think of it like this:

- `typeof`: primitives
- `Object.prototype.toString`: Objects (and primitives)

Here's a good resource that explains JavaScript's data type detection: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

But here's a routine I found that works in every case I've needed. The order of operations and methods chosen have been specifically optimized for speed. (FYI, your use cases may vary, so some of the orders might best be switched, but overall would work really well.):

```
type = type || 
(   function detect( coerce )
    {   
        if (typeof data === 'string')
            return (coerce=document.getElementById(data)) ? (data=coerce,'element') : 'string';

        if (data.type && (data.srcElement||data.target))
            return 'event';

        if (data.nodeType != void 0)
            return 'element';

        if (data[0] != void 0 && data[0].nodeType != void 0)
            return 'elements';

        if (Object.prototype.call(data) === '[object Array]')
            return 'array';

        if (data/1 === data)
            return 'number';

        return 'object';
    }
)();
```

And since you are mentioning the `Array Prototype`, my instinct is to tell you: "Please do not amend the Array Prototype." (It can cause environments to become unstable with iteration and namespaces.)

Everybody else seems to have provided a wealth of information too! Nice!

Comment: Well, in regards to the selected answer, `typeof` will work that way for the sake of Objects, but not overall. Maybe he was just demonstrating the fact.

Comment: BTW, I just remembered a syntactical shorthand: `{}.toString.call`; (I believe that's correct. Creates a disposable object though...)